# Use getAsJsonArray on JsonObject

Tags: java, post, gson

I have problem with convert JsonObject to JsonArray. Im use Ion and Gson library.

I want get some information with postmetod to sqlite.

```
    [2015-11-08 22:11:58]: array (
  0 => 
  array (
    '2014-01' => 
    array (
      'income' => '78294.34',
      'expense' => '1000',
      'result' => '77294.34',
    ),
    '2014-02' => 
    array (
      'income' => '3245.34',
      'expense' => '1000',
      'result' => '2245.34',
    ),
    '2014-03' => 
    array (
      'income' => '5637.1',
      'expense' => '1000',
      'result' => '4637.1',
    ),
    '2014-04' => 
    array (
      'income' => '89345.55',
      'expense' => '1000',
      'result' => '88345.55',
    ),
    '2014-11' => 
    array (
      'income' => '9348',
      'expense' => '1000',
      'result' => '8348',
    ),
    '2014-12' => 
    array (
      'income' => '384836',
      'expense' => '1000',
      'result' => '383836',
    ),
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    2014 => 
    array (
      'income' => '570706.33',
      'expense' => '6000',
      'result' => '564706.33',
    ),
  ),
)
```

Im trying take date, income, expense and result to database. I havent problem with set double to database.

```
//this normal work, show me string with "0"
System.out.println(jsonElements.get(0).toString());
//but i have problem when im using
jsonElements.get(0).getAsJsonArray().get(0).get(result).toString();
```

I have no idea what should i do this. In logcat i have error "this is not jsonarray". I will be really grateful for the help.

Comment: On jsonElements.get(0).getAsJsonArray().get(0).toString(); i have that same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found way to do this. Im so sorry for do problem. I hope it will be helpful for someone.

```
System.out.println(jsonElements.get(0).getAsJsonObject().entrySet().iterator().next().getKey());
System.out.println(jsonElements.get(0).getAsJsonObject().entrySet().iterator().next().getValue().getAsJsonObject().get("income").toString());
System.out.println(jsonElements.get(0).getAsJsonObject().entrySet().iterator().next().getValue().getAsJsonObject().get("expense").toString());
System.out.println(jsonElements.get(0).getAsJsonObject().entrySet().iterator().next().getValue().getAsJsonObject().get("result").toString());
```